# Why am I getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in my code?

Tags: python, typeerror, primes

I'm designing a program that prints prime factors of a number.

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    if x >= 0:
        break

ranger = list(range(1, x+1))
counter = 0

#The first for loop checks if the number is a factor
for i in ranger:
    if x % i == 0:
        #The second for loop checks if the number is prime
        for element in range(1, i+1 ):
            if i % element == 0:
                counter += 1
                if counter == 2:
                    prime_factors = []
                    prime_factors += i
                #Counter having a value of 2 means the number is prime

print(prime_factors)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\primefactors.py", line 18, in <module>

    prime_factors += i
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

But I don't seem to understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: What you're trying to do with `prime_factors = [] ; prime_factors += i` would be more simply and clearly written as `prime_factors = [i]`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `prime_factors.append(i)`, as you add to `list`s using `.append()`, not the addition operator :)

(`python` will throw errors if you try to `+` a `list` and an `int` as it's not possible to add them together)

Answer (score 0):

The `list` addition operator is defined only on two lists, not on a list and an integer.  Python was trying to do a `list.__add__` on `prime_factors` and `i`, which includes iterating through the elements of `i`.  That's where you got the error.

The correct command would be

```
prime_factors.append(i)
```

With that change, your program correctly prints only the lowest prime factor.  You also need to move your initializations and checks to the proper places:

- set `prime_factors` to the empty list only at the start of your program.
- set `counter` back to 0 for each suspected prime factor.
- check the value of `counter` only *after* you've looked at all smaller numbers.

Comment: I did some experimentation, and it appears that `+` doesn't work with lists and non-list iterables, but `+=` does. For instance, `prime_factors += range(5)` results in `prime_factors` being equal to `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

When the left operand of `+=` is a list, python expects an iterable on the right side. You can use `append` instead, or `prime_factors +=[i]`. Also, it looks like you screwed up the identation or something; your present code doesn't make any sense. For instance, your `prime_factors +=i` line is always preceded by `prime_factors = []`. If you were to replace `+=` with `append`, you would end up with those two line having the same functionality as if you had one line that just said `prime_factors = [i]`.